# Twisted Application getting name

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.client

I am trying to set the name of the application in twisted and would like to get the name later on using the variable "app"

```
app = service.Application("TestingApp")
```

I could not find anything like "app.getName()". Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

The name is available via the `IService.name` attribute:

```
>>> from twisted.application.service import Application, IService
>>> IService(Application("Some name")).name
'Some name'
>>>
```

Comment: I would like to get the name from the "app" rather than passing the "Some name" to IService. I create the application in one file "app" and would like to fetch the name from a different file/object using "app". Here "App" is a global variable. Right now I kept a wrapper singleton object with a user defined get function to get the name. In your solution, I still have to pass the name and as i mentioned the "App" is global variable accesible from anywhere and would like to the get the name of the application from anywhere using just "App"

Comment: It works but it fails on MultiService with the following error.    observer = application.getComponent(ILogObserver, None)
AttributeError: MultiService instance has no attribute 'getComponent'

Comment: True.  `MultiService` isn't a `Componentized` (which is what `Application` returns).  `MultiService` just has a `name` attribute.